# getBoundingClientRect() showing different values on load vs scroll

Tags: theme-development, javascript

I'm working on a [site](https://gosafariadventure.com) for a client and trying to implement custom parallax functionality. I have used the following code -

```
var inView = function(element) {
    // get window height
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    // Get Element Height
    var elementHeight = element.clientHeight;
    // get number of pixels that the document is scrolled
    var scrollY = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;

    // get current scroll position (distance from the top of the page to the bottom of the current viewport)
    var scrollPosition = scrollY + windowHeight;

    var elementPosition = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + scrollY;

    var elementScrolled = elementPosition + element.clientHeight + windowHeight

    // is scroll position greater than element position? (is element in view?)
    if (scrollPosition > elementPosition && scrollPosition < elementScrolled) {
    return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Get all the elements to be parallaxed
const parallaxElements = {
    element: document.querySelectorAll('#header-image img'),
    ratio: 0.25
}

// The parallax function
const parallax = elements => {
    let items       = [...elements.element],
        itemRatio   = elements.ratio

    if ('undefined' !== items && items.length > 0 ) {
        items.forEach( item => {
            if ( inView(item) == true ) {
                item.style.transform = 'translate3d(0, ' + (itemRatio * (window.innerHeight - item.getBoundingClientRect().top)) + 'px ,0)'
            }
        })
    }
}

//If element is in viewport, set its position
parallax(parallaxElements)

//Call the function on scroll
window.onscroll = () => {
    parallax(parallaxElements)
}
```

It's working ok except that when the page is loaded initially and the user starts scrolling, the position of element (`#header-image img` in this case) changes abruptly. I did some digging and noticed that the value of `getBoundingClientRect().top` is causing the issue.

When the page is loaded, it has some value, and as soon as the user starts scrolling, it abruptly changes to another value.

I am not able to figure out why this is happening. `getBoundingClientRect().top` is supposed to get the value of element from top of viewport, right?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Pls check the screenshot of inspect element below -
[image]

Comment: is this a WordPress question? This looks like a frontend JS/CSS question, generic JS/CSS questions go on stackoverflow

Comment: Ohk! Done!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71157772/getboundingclientrect-showing-different-values-on-load-vs-scroll